# Combobox with AutoComplete

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox, disabled-input

How to create a combobox with AutoCompletion? The following code works well if combobox is editable. How to achieve auto completion in non editable combobox?

```
JCombobox execBrokerCombobox = new AutoCompletionComboBox();
((AutoCompletionComboBox) execBrokerCombobox).setStrict(false);
execBrokerCombobox.setEditable(false);
```

Comment: I'm sorry?  What's the point?  If you can't type into the field, what's the point of having autocomplete?

Comment: Non editable combobox ? Then what is the meaning of AutoComplete if value cant be edit?

Comment: Wen I click on the combobox, the list of items will be displayed. Consider ("ABS","DFG","vcb","mas") . Now I press D the focus must go automatically to DFG item.

Comment: @user5367186 that is default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Glazed Lists](http://www.glazedlists.com/)** for this purpose.

**Example:**

```
JComboBox execBrokerCombobox = new JComboBox();
String[] obj = new String[5];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   obj[i] = "Option" + (i+1);
}
AutoCompleteSupport.install(jexecBrokerCombobox, GlazedLists.eventListOf(obj));
```